# Add-Computer and NewName, order of execution and traces?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[Powershell enthusiast - Novice in AD here]

I have a question to which I have not been able to find a direct answer, when I add a computer to the domain with something like:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "CONTOSO.COM" -Credential $creds -OUPath $ou -NewName $newHostname
```

The renaming bit of the command happens after or before joining to the domain?

If it happens after, doesn't joining a machine with a particular hostname and then renaiming said hostname leave traces or "trash" in registry entries, databases, etc?

Documentation of your answers will be much appreciated if possible, as I'm dealing with a Domain Admin that does not want me to use this command to join machines and just my word won't work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not n front of a pc so cannot test but if memory serves the computer is joined to the domain with the new name, so it is one step process.

PoSH will change the name and then join the domain with that computer name.

Documentation does not talk about this specifically but worth a read nonetheless [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1)